# Package installed, but with error

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

```
CentOS 6.5, Puppet Enterprise 3.1.1.

Given this declaration:
    package { vim:  ensure => present  }

The following error is displayed:
   Error: Could not find package vim
   Error: /Stage[main]//Node[web.localtest.com]/Package[vim]/ensure: change
   from absent to present failed: Could not find package vim

Nevertheless, vim has been installed.

How to fix it?

Note: There is no error when testig with htop.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Centos, I believe the package you're looking for is "vim-enhanced" ... not just "vim".  It is very likely that the package was already installed before you ran the test.